# Equivalents of super.onSaveInstanceState() and super.onRestoreInstanceState() to use in onPause() and onCreate() respectively to save view data

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, state-saving

`super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` and `super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` automatically saves views, but `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` aren't called always. I need equivalents of above two super calls to use in `onPause()`, to save views when I leave activity and restore saved views in `onCreate()'. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried SharedPreferences?

Comment: what exactly about it? All I know is you can save int, boolean, string , etc and get it back via set and get methods, but I don't know how you would save the layout as easily as super.onSaveInstanceState(). any suggestions?